# Javascript increment a variable in a function

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, switch-statement, increment

Hey guys I'm new to programming, I need to make a website for school.
I want to open the next page when pressing the arrow keys. So I thougt,
I can put the URLs into an array an increment the index, when the button is pressed.
Unfortunately I get some random numbers from 1 to 3 when I press the down key.

```
const url = ['/#t1', '/#t2', '/#t3', './contact.html', './404.html'];

var index = 0;

$(document).keydown(function(e) {
    switch(e.which) {
       case 38: // up
           up();
       break;

       case 40: // down
           down();
       break;

       default: return; 
   }
   e.preventDefault();
});

function up() {
    index = index - 1;
    alert(index);
    window.location.href = url[index];
}

function down() {
    index = index + 1;
    alert(index);
    window.location.href = url[index];
}
```

Comment: Need to realize that when you switch to a new page the current code is gone and new page loads with a completely new instance. So index will get set to zero  each time you load this same code

Comment: You can use `sessionStorage` to save data between pages.

Comment: I agree with charliefl, sounds like it's reloading. Also I'd move your prevent default up to the first line of your function.

Comment: `location.hash = url[index]` instead, for hashes.

Comment: Ok this makes sense, do you know how prevent this? Everything is in a app.js file.

Comment: Oh, I should have also told you to remove  `/#` from those hashes, in your Array, as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick way to solve this without using storage is to find the index in the array rather than keeping track of it. You can do that like so:

```js
const url = ['/list', '/of', '/urls'];

//find index of current url in array
let index = url.indexOf(window.location.pathname)

if(index == -1){
 //url is not in the array
 windows.alert("invalid url")
}
```

Edit: I agree with Michael Geary that is is a bad idea for a real world website

Answer (score 1):

## Don't do this!

What you're doing is a fun exercise, but it breaks the normal page scrolling that any visitor to your site may expect to work.

When I view a web page, I scroll through it using the up and down arrow keys. For example, open the [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/) home page or [Hacker News](https://news.ycombinator.com/) and hit the down arrow a few times, then the up arrow. That scrolling is how web pages are supposed to work.

There are some exceptions. The [Google](https://www.google.com/) home page opens with the the text cursor in the main input field, and the down arrow opens a list of recent searches. That's perfectly reasonable.

But having the down arrow jump to a whole new section of the page - or another page entirely! - is not what visitors expect. Don't do it unless you have a really good reason.

If you do have a good reason, I will be curious to hear it! :-)

Comment: You are absolutely right, this is not a good way to design a website. I'm just having fun and trying different things. I will never use this for real world apps, I promise :). Edit: I also need to mention that scrolling is not enabled on those sites.

Comment: It's for school. Perfectly breakable!

Comment: Whew! You had me scared there. But yeah, as a fun learning exercise this is very cool. In that case, the solution that @CWB posted is very nice.